# How do I make my highstock's graph y axis is just absolute value?

Tags: highcharts

Hello I'm original using highcharts
because my clients has need to see different view based on time,
like 1day,2day,3day,7day,1month, so I figure out highstock is more resemble
to this, but using highstock is missing some feature.
  while I successfully figure out how to add legend(legend), change point display
(tooltip:formatter), change xaxis display and navigator display(dateTimeLabelFormats),
I see the display of line just like stock, which means:
  it doesn't consider the absolute value of which too much, like I have connected terminals varying from 8-10, registered terminals varying from 2-3, unfornately it will draw registered terminals above connected terminals, which doesn't quite make sense, (besides the yAxis display is not correct, when it draw 5, the point above which actually says 4..), I also tried

```
plotOptions: {series: {compare: 'percent'}},
```

and

```
plotOptions: {series: {compare: 'percent'}},
```

but doesn't work, the y Axis is still quite confusing,

does anybody has a good solution? Thanks.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean by absolute and "it will draw registered terminals above connected terminals". Do you have an example you can put up?

Comment: Could you prepare example in jsfiddle and then describe what you mean by "absolute and "it will draw registered terminals above connected terminals"

Comment: I assume his problem is he wants the y-Axis to show the value of his datapoints instead of the change relative to the first y-value which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently. It basically come from leaving useless parts of the example code in :D

Taking out the

```
plotOptions: {series: {compare: 'percent'}},
```

part should make it use the absolute values.

I assume taking out the compare parameter alone should be enough as well but since its the only thing you set from the plotOptions there is no need to keep the rest.